# Angular 2 component cannot retrieve data from service

Tags: angular, angular2-services

The situation is quite simple - I'm trying to get data from Angular 2 service but target array is always empty. I can see that call to api return data and status 200 and there is no errors in console.
Here is my basic service:

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    items = [];
    constructor(private http:Http) {
        this.loadItems();
    }
    loadItems() {
        this.http.get('http://localhost:58928/api/front')
            .map((res: Response) => {
                return res.json();
            })
    }
}
```

And here is component:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from './../../services/data-service';

@Component({
    selector: 'items-list',
    template: `
        <div class="container">
    <div class="items" *ngFor="let item of items|sort:'DESC';let i = index;trackBy: item?.id">
    <a href="/items/{{item.id}}">
        <mdl-card class="demo-card-square" mdl-shadow="2" mdl-card-expand>
        <mdl-card-media>
        <img src="{{item.imgUrl}}" alt="{{item.name}}" style="max-width: 100%">
         </mdl-card-media>
            <mdl-card-title mdl-card-expand>
                <h2 mdl-card-title-text>{{item.name}}</h2>
            </mdl-card-title>
            <mdl-card-supporting-text>
                {{item.shortDescription}}
            </mdl-card-supporting-text>
            <mdl-card-actions mdl-card-border>
                <h6 class='mdl-color-text--grey-600'>От {{item.priceFrom}} рублей.</h6>
            </mdl-card-actions>
        </mdl-card>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
`,
    styles: [
        `
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-content: space-around;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
}

.items{
    margin: auto;
    padding-top: 1%;
    padding-bottom: 1%;
}

a {
text-decoration: none;
}

`
    ]
})

export class ItemsList {
    @Input() items = [];
    constructor(private dataService: DataService) {
        this.items = dataService.items;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, when you do this:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    items = [];
    constructor(private http:Http) {
        this.loadItems();
    }
    loadItems() {
        this.http.get('http://localhost:58928/api/front')
            .map((res: Response) => {
                return res.json();
            })
    }
}
```

You call your web API and just map the result, but you don't assign it to anything. Maybe you can modify it like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    items = [];
    constructor(private http:Http) {
        this.loadItems();
    }
    loadItems() {
        this.http.get('http://localhost:58928/api/front')
            .map((res: Response) => {
                return res.json();
            }).subscribe(data => this.items = data);
    }
}
```

This time, as soon as the data are there, `items` will contain them. However, doing this like this is not optimal because it could be that your component loads before the HTTP call is done, and in this case, you'll get an empty array as well. The best would be to either returns the observable (return by `map`) and make your component subscribed to it or create a new observable that fires when `items` are initialized.

Here is an example of the first possibility: http://plnkr.co/edit/DD8fqa2dJGksCtOlolO2?p=preview

This approach works, this only thing is that if you call "loadItems" twice, the HTTP call will be done twice. If you want some caching, something more advanced have to be developped with Observables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you point me please to some informatio regarding using Observables?

Comment: I added a plunker to my answer to show you an easy way to do what you want.