# Angular: component doesn't retrieve data from service

Tags: angular

I have the following service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { IRecordEvent } from 'app/shared/model/record-event.model';

type EntityArrayResponseType = HttpResponse<IRecordEvent[]>;

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class RecordsService {
   public resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/record-events';

   constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {}

   find(recordId: number): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
      return this.http
         .get<IRecordEvent[]>(`${this.resourceUrl}/record-id/${recordId}`, { observe: 'response' })
         .pipe(map((res: EntityArrayResponseType) => this.convertDateArrayFromServer(res)));
   }

   protected convertDateArrayFromServer(res: EntityArrayResponseType): EntityArrayResponseType {
      if (res.body) {
          res.body.forEach((recordEvent: IRecordEvent) => {
            recordEvent.eventDate = recordEvent.eventDate ? moment(recordEvent.eventDate) : undefined;
          });
      }
return res;
}
```

And the following component (I put ellipsis to simplify code):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { IRecord } from 'app/shared/model/record.model';
import { IRecordEvent } from 'app/shared/model/record-event.model';
import { RecordsService } from './records.service';
import { HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
   ...
})
export class DetailledRecordComponent implements OnInit {
    recordEvents?: IRecordEvent[] | null;

    constructor(protected recordsService: RecordsService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {        
       this.setRecordEvents();
    }

    setRecordEvents(): void {
        this.recordsService
          .find(this.record.id!)
          .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<IRecordEvent[]>) => (this.recordEvents = res.body));
   }
}
```

The service retrieves the following data from backend (8 recordEvents with same recordId):

```
0: {id: 2, eventDate: "2020-07-09", type: "AFF_DT_TRF_ACC_PREV", recordId: 1, recordCode: "D745/012561"}
1: {id: 3, eventDate: "2020-07-08", type: "AFF_DT_RECEV_DEM_PTF_PREV", recordId: 1, recordCode: "D745/012561"}
2: {id: 4, eventDate: "2020-07-08", type: "AFF_DT_ENV_FACT_PREV", recordId: 1, recordCode: "D745/012561"}
3: {id: 5, eventDate: "2020-07-09", type: "AFF_DT_ENV_CV_RACC_PREV", recordId: 1, recordCode: "D745/012561"}
4: {id: 6, eventDate: "2020-07-09", type: "AFF_DT_VAL_DDESC_PREV", recordId: 1, recordCode: "D745/012561"}
5: {id: 7, eventDate: "2020-07-09", type: "AFF_DT_AFFEC_CA_REA", recordId: 1, recordCode: "D745/012561"}
6: {id: 8, eventDate: "2020-07-08", type: "AFF_DT_ENV_PTF_REA", recordId: 1, recordCode: "D745/012561"}
7: {id: 9, eventDate: "2020-07-08", type: "AFF_DT_DMEO_REA", recordId: 1, recordCode: "D745/012561"}
```

In Google Chrome inspector I can see that it is correctly get from backend:
[image: Google Chrome inspector on service]

My problem is that the component does not retrieve this data. I always get undefined:

[image: Google Chrome inspector component]

I used Observables though ([Angular 2 component cannot retrieve data from service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719503/angular-2-component-cannot-retrieve-data-from-service)), I don't understand what I'm missing here.

I noticed something weird: when I debug the interface with Google Chrome's inspector I have this behavior:

1- In the service, the parameter (recordId) is set (with `find()` method in component) but res is not
[image]

2- The component inits `this.recordsEvents` with undefined

3- Only after these two steps the service gets the objects from backend

Why the data is not retrieved in first step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @bernatampera pointed out, the component or the html has to manage an asynchronous call. He suggested to do so with `| async` in the html but I found another way that I find cleaner:

In my component, instead of assigning value directly, I call a onSuccess() method:

```
setRecordEvents(): void {
   this.recordsService
     .find(this.record.id!)
     .subscribe(
         (res: HttpResponse<IRecordEvent[]>) => this.onSuccess(res.body),
         () => this.onError()
     );
}
```

And I assign my value in this onSuccess method:

```
protected onSuccess(body: IRecordEvent[] | null): void {
   this.recordEvents = body;
}
```

I still use `*ngIf="recordEvents"` in my html to avoid compilation errors.

Comment: it would help if you also shared why this works and why it's a good solution. Might be educational for other people with the same issue

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you are experiencing is because the component is rendered the first time before the observable has emmited any value.

The optimal solution would be to use the async pipe to wait for the async value.

It would look like this.

```
 export class DetailledRecordComponent implements OnInit {
        recordEvents?: Observable<IRecordEvent[]> = this.recordsService
          .find(this.record.id!); 
    
        constructor(protected recordsService: RecordsService) {}
}
```

And then in the .html file,

```
<div *ngIf="recordEvents$ | async as recordEvents"> 
    // Here you can use the recordEvents property recordEvents as desired
</div>
```

Ask here, if there's something to further clarify..

Comment: Thanks for help. It means that I'd have an Observable in my component and another one in my service? I tried to out your first code block but I have the following error: `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<EntityArrayResponseType>'`

Comment: If I make no change on my component and I only add the code for the html, I have this `[INFO] Argument of type 'IRecordEvent[] | null | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Promise<unknown> | null | undefined'.
[INFO] Type 'IRecordEvent[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Promise<unknown>': then, catch, [Symbol.toStringTag]`

Comment: I don't get why it talks about Promises whereas I am using Observable

Comment: The async pipe will subscribe to an observable or a promise, that's the reason of the default error message. You should also be able to use the observable in the service directly in the .html file, but it's cleaner to add an observable in the component.

Comment: @Héloïse The error `Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable<EntityArrayResponseType>'` could be appearing because the data type you are using is different that the one I expected. I'll edit the answer deleting the map operation. See what value is emitted then and use it to display your message.

Comment: Ow ok I understand how | async works now but I don't like the fact that I have to put an Observable in my component. I found another way to manage asynchronous call, I put the answer below.